# How can I assemble a file name from list items on copy module?

Tags: ansible

On my Ansible playbook I have this list as a variable:

```
 collections: [customers licenses system]
```

The list is used in more than one place.
In one place I need to copy existing files containing my data (which are `customers.json`, `licenses.json`, `system.json`).

This does not work:

```
 - copy: src="{{ item }}.json" dest=~/import/
   with_items: "{{ collections }}"
```

It concatenates the list first then my file extension so it is like `files/customers licenses system.json`.

This does not work either:

```
 - copy: src={{ item ~ ".json" }} dest=~/import/
   with_items: "{{ collections }}"
```

In this case it is ignoring the file extension, the first item looks like `files/customers`.

Is there a way I can get it working without duplicating the variable or renaming the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that this variable as it's currently defined is just a single string, and not a list of 3 items:

```
collections: [customers licenses system]
```

Here's a quick example to demonstrate:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    collections: [customers licenses system]

  tasks:
    - debug: var=item
      with_items: collections
```

The output of the above is:

```
TASK: [debug var=item] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=customers licenses system) => {
    "item": "customers licenses system"
}
```

So ansible is treating `collections` as a list with one item in it.  The proper way to define the list is:

```
collections: ['customers', 'licenses',  'system']
```

or, you can also define it this way:

```
collections:
  - customers
  - licenses
  - system
```

When you change `collections` to one of these then the output of the above test becomes:

```
TASK: [debug var=item] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=customers) => {
    "item": "customers"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=licenses) => {
    "item": "licenses"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=system) => {
    "item": "system"
}
```

Change the way your list is defined and the copy module should work as you'd expect it.